# automating .bat file to configure AWS S3

Tags: batch-file, amazon-web-services, scripting, amazon-s3, cmd

So I am trying to automate a .bat file for AWS S3 configuration.  At this point I type in AWS configuration to the command line and the precede to enter the AWS access key, secret key, region name and output manually.   I am new to scripting and I'm sure its a simple solution. How can I put these 4 things (key, secret key, region, output) into the .bat file so I can just run the .bat script to configure the file.  Basically how can I enter this Amazon web service S3 data automatically.

Answer (score 1):

for key and secret, include the following lines in your batch file:

- set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
- set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key

[AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

for region name, use "-- region" switch

for output, redirect to output file, e.g., aws s3 ... >> logfile.log